# Using jquery Flexslider plugin as a container for other controls

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I wonder if anyone has worked with the jquery flexslider much? I'm looking to use it as follows:

- I would like to turn it into a container into which other controls(textboxes, comboboxes, buttons etc.) can be dragged, dropped into and configured **at design time**. Has anyone come across anything like this before? In its current form, I can only work with objects at runtime but I want to drag and drop objects into the slider at design time and have the items and their markup generated dynamically.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Gabriel, all I am asking is for examples(if any) where the flexislider has been used as a container within which you can drag and drop controls at design time. Say I am designing a page; I want to drag in a slider; and inside this slider; in turn drag various controls like textbox, checkbox, button etc. Currently, the flexislider can be used to display a list of images, media files all in a slideshow. What I want , is to pass different types of controls to it at design time; so when it renders, say slide 1 has a checkbox control, slide 2 has a grid, slide 3 has a series of textboxes etc.